# jQuery count nested buttons in nested and (initially) hidden DIVs

Tags: jquery, count, nested

I have some PHP code generating HTML and depending on some conditions in some DIVs some buttons may be dynamically created using jQuery (**after document load**). The DIVs that may contain buttons, have an initial css hidden state.

While the containing DIVs are hidden I need to:

- Count how many buttons are there
- In case there's only one button, return id of the button

HTML

```
<div id="row-buttons">
    <div> <!-- dynamically generated unknown id --> 
        <div id="classes-buttons-placeholder" style="display: none;">
            <!-- a DIV that may contain x buttons dynamically generated  -->
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="subjects-buttons-placeholder" style="display: none;">
            <div>
                <!-- another DIV that may contain x buttons dynamically generated  -->
                <button id="Music" class="subjects-button"> Music</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

In the example above, how can I verify if is there only one button and in this case return the id?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code

```
$(function(){
    $("div[id*='-buttons-placeholder']:hidden").each(function(){
    var buttons = $(this).find("button");
    if(buttons.length == 1) {
        alert("Button inside " + $(this).attr("id") + ": " + buttons.attr("id"));
    }
  });
});
```

Gives output like `Button inside subjects-buttons-placeholder: Music`

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/vnathalye/bk4wbp6u/

Comment: I see that the fiddle works perfectly but in my sources is not working. Could it be due to the buttons are created dynamically? I recall that some functions will not work on dynamically created objects...

Comment: My fault I was testing before the buttons are created ;-) Working!!! Thanks

Answer (score 0):

first of all itertate over each repeated div and then under div find button and return id

```js
$('.master-divs').each(function(){
    
  b = $(this).find('button');
  if(b.length>0){
  button_id= b.attr('id');
    alert(button_id);
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="row-buttons">
    <div> <!-- dynamically generated unknown id --> 
        <div id="classes-buttons-placeholder"  class="master-divs" style="display: none;">
            <!-- a DIV that may contain x buttons dynamically generated  -->
        </div>
        <div style="clear:both"></div>
        <div id="subjects-buttons-placeholder" class="master-divs" style="display: none;">
            <div>
                <!-- another DIV that may contain x buttons dynamically generated  -->
                <button id="Music" class="subjects-button"> Music</button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```